# Had new tires put on back or car, and rotated to front, suddenly i have break steer on hard braking

Tags: brakes, tires

so I had a new set of Yokohama yk740 put on the back of my yaris se, replacing the Bridgestone turanzas I had on it, now if I brake aggressively, I get significant break steer to the passenger side...

What could have been done accidentally to cause this? what should I Look for to diagnose it?

Also the sway and wobble in the back end seems to have dramatically increased, the Yokohamas were supposed to be better tires, Do they have weaker sidewalls than the turanza? Or am I just suddenly noticing suspension wear because of correcting for break steer.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if they over torqued the lugs on one side or the other, or possibly *didn't tighten them at all* (which would be far worse). You may want to first check to ensure the lugs are at least tight, then if they are, take it back to the shop where you had the work done and have them take the lugs off both sides and then retorque them. Putting new tires on the vehicle alone should not have caused the issue you are seeing. Something else is going on and should be investigated, but you ALWAYS start at what you just did to see if there's an issue there.

Comment: I don't have enough to call this an answer but I'll make a comment. Are the sizes exactly the same? I just swapped some wheels and tyres from one Yaris to another and I have a similar situation only mine wants to steer away under acceleration. Running odd tyres can highlight minor alignment characteristics especially when one pair is a soft compound whilst the other pair is a hard compound.

Comment: Same size, rear are supposed to be slightly better tires.

Answer (score 1):

So you rotated the new tires to the front on a front drive car.  Are the rear tires worn?  If so that can cause your back end problem - when you brake, the weight transfers to the front tires and the weight on the back end goes light.  If the tires are worn, they can break loose. The effect would be oversteer - front going where you point, the back end swinging out.

As to the uneven braking...?  Uneven caliper pressure?  Bad alignment?

Comment: You have checked the tyre pressures? as a difference is a classic cause of the symptoms you mention.